# Java SimpleDateFormat time wierdness

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a date string into a `java.util.Date` using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`; however, the resulting formatted date is wrong.

Here is a test case showing the issue:

```
@Test
public void testSimpleDateFormat() throws Exception {
    String dateString = "2016-03-03 11:50:39.5960000";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");
    Date date = format.parse(dateString);

    assertEquals(dateString, format.format(date));
}
```

This results in the following failure:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :2016-03-03 11:50:39.5960000
Actual   :2016-03-03 13:29:59.0000000
```

The date is correct, but the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds are all wrong. Why is `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` messing up the time on my date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pattern says that `5960000` is a number of milliseconds. That represents 5960 seconds, so approximately 1 hour and 39 minutes, which explains the difference between the date you obtain and the initial one.

Comment: Ah this makes sense, code works if I drop the trailing zeros. Does this mean that `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't understand precision past 3, or does it need a different format string to support this?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to remove the trailing zeros before parsing, so that the final number is a number of milliseconds rather than a number of "decimicroseconds".

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` does not understand precision at all. It only understand, that where you write `S` letters in pattern - there will be milliseconds. It parse `.` as a character, not as a decimal-delimiter, you can even put a smile `:)` there for example, it will give no changes. So, when you write `SSSSSSS` it mean 7-digit **integer** number of milliseconds, the result of it is described in answer. And as of this [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), yes, it does not understand anything less than milliseconds.

Comment: @TEXHIK actually, you could use S, SSS, SSSSSSS or SSSSSSSSSSSSS, and it wouldn't change anything. It always means that the whole number must be interpreted as a number of milliseconds.

Comment: @JBNizet the number of `S` **will** change the behaviour - it will change number of digits, that will be parsed as ms.

Comment: This is very strange behaviour. So ms pattern is ignoring number of S letters... with one exception - it see, when there more than 3 letters, it adding zeros' at the start...

Comment: It's adding 0 at the start when formatting. But when parsing, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using old classes that have proven to be confusing, troublesome, and poorly designed. Avoid them. They have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

The java.time classes use resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), for up to nine digits of a decimal fraction of second. More than enough for your six digits ([microseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)).

Your input string is close to the standard ISO 8601 format. That format is used by default in java.time for parsing/generating string representations of date-time values. So, need to specify parsing pattern.

Morph your input string into standard format. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-03-03 11:50:39.5960000";
String inputStandardized = input.replace( " " , "T" );
```

Parse that string into a date-time object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStandardized );
```

To get an actual moment on the timeline, assign an offset or time zone intended for this input.

If in UTC, create a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

If a specific time was intended, create a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

## Before Java 8

If you do not yet have Java 8 technology available, consider adding either the [backport of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (the inspiration for java.time). For Android, there is a specific wrapper of the backport, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: This is useful for anyone who can use Java 8 for sure; however, I am stuck with Java 7 and was not looking to introduce any additional dependencies (e.g. JodaTime).

Comment: @shuniar Many people including myself consider it mandatory to add either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the [backport of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to most any pre-Java-8 project. The old date-time classes really are that bad. Do what you have to do… but you’ve been warned. ;-)